# Laravel SubDomain Routing

Tags: laravel, routes

I hope someone can assist.

I have setup a subdomain using Route::Domain - account.example.co.uk but for some reason on my Laravel Forge production server the subdomain route is being changed to account.example.com rather than the correct domain?

As you can see from the screenshot below,this is what is appearing when i run php artisan route:list on the production server?

I have setup the correct DNS routing via Digital Ocean.

[View Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8mP0.png)

Comment: Recommend pasting the text that's in the link as text into this question. This way, the details will be available to anyone in the future if the link goes away.

Comment: Are you sure the Laravel app is returning the redirect to `account.example.com`? Maybe it's the web server (nginx, Apache, etc) who is changing the domain. Could you double check that?